# what is the best procedure to make a copy of the Array in java

Tags: java

In below code, assigning the a array object to another array object t. these two are different objects in the memory right? why changing one object is impacting other object content?

```
package test.main;

import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class C1 implements I1,I2{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [][] a= {{1,2}};    

        int [][] t= {};
        t=a;
        t[0][0] = 3;
        System.out.println("t "+t[0][0]);
        System.out.println("a "+a[0][0]);
    }

    @Override
    public void staticMethod() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

output:

```
t 3
a 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> these two are different objects in the memory right?

No, they are two different *variables* that refer to the very same array *object*.

The key is in understanding the difference between a reference variable and the object that it refers to. If you want to create two arrays that are completely different then you will want to use `System.arraycopy(...)`. If you need to copy the array items as well, and if it is an array of *objects*, of references acxtually, then you'll need to do a deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

```
int [][] a= {{1,2}};
```

This creates one object, referenced by the variable `a`.

```
int [][] t= {};
```

This creates another object, referenced by the variable `t`.

```
t=a;
```

Now the object formerly referenced by `t` is "forgotten", and `t` points to the same object as `a`.

That's why, when you use the variable `t` to modify the object, it is the same as using the variable `a`. It is just 2 ways of accessing the same thing. Like 2 doors to access the same room.

Comment: thanks, what is the best way to make a copy of an array in this case? using clone() or using temporary array?

Comment: Neither of them. As @HovercraftFullOfEels pointed out, you can use `System.arraycopy()`.

Comment: In java 1.6 , they have introduced the Array Util class to do the same: int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(a, newLength);